# Angular 2 rc 1 canActivate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there some similar like @CanActivate in the new rc router or do I have to use routerOnActivate and navigate back if it is not activable?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as of 15 May 2016 is that @CanActivate functionality is currently not implemented in the release candidate and other than using `router-deprecated` or switching to an alternate router implementation such as `ngrx` there really isn't anything to do other than wait.

Here's an open issue asking for a solution: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8655

Here is a [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WLSNV3V1AKdwLwRiLuN7JqbPBKQ_S5quRlcT5LPIldw/edit#) which took me ages to find which talks about the proposed router refactorings (you can find mention of @CanActivate in the doc).

Answer (score 1):

To use `@CanActivate` you need to import `router-deprecated` instead of `router`.

---

If you want to use new `Router`,

there is [routerCanDeactivate()](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b98c9e74e1ad73dc48eb67471ee91f4a1c01dfb6/modules/%40angular/router/src/interfaces.ts) lifeCycleHook which is possibly the replacement for `@CanActivate`.

The only difference would be that, now you'll allow/disallow navigation on previous route instead of the next.

Comment: Are you sure `CanDeactivate` can be a replacement for `CanActivate`? I think `CanActivate´ is just not yet implemented in the new router.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, no . how can I be sure. I expressed my doubt in my answer. Maybe you're right, but I really don't know.