# limit angular2 routes to authenticated users

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack, jwt

I was looking to implement angular2-jwt's ex

```
@CanActivate(() => tokenNotExpired())
```

In order to limit navigation on certain routes to users with a non-expired JWT. However @CanActivate looks to be deprecated in the r.c. router. How can route access to only authenticated user be achieved in the new router? Sort of like the interceptor in Angular 1.x.

Answer (score 0):

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225831/angular-2-rc-1-canactivate) should answer your question.

Angular made router from beta deprecated and it's simply not yet implemented in RC.